# MongoDB: counting documents in multi-document transactions

Tags: mongodb, transactions

I saw that `estimatedDocumentCount()` could get inconsistent results in certain occasions. By the other hand, `countDocuments()` will always be precise, but it also costs more.

So, what would be some good use cases in which `estimatedDocumentCount()` would be preferable versus `countDocuments()`? How much performance we lose when using `countDocuments()` in relation to the other method? And also what is the "safe way" of using `estimatedDocumentCount()`?

I would like a comparison of these two methods in the context of multi-document transactions, in order to decide which to use and in which scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the use case, 'costs more' can mean, unfortunately, 'database outage'.

`estimatedDocumentCount()` is just reading metadata from the collection; it's as close to zero cost as it's possible to be. `countDocuments()`, on the other hand, is, well, actually counting documents, as the name implies. It's more accurate for that instant, if that's what you need.

However, one must be very aware of the pathological nature of the no-filter ( i.e., a query of `{}`) form of `countDocuments()`. In the case of a very large collection, e.g., billions of documents, your first clue that that's not the right choice is when the database cluster experiences cascade failure as the servers page themselves into the ground.

As such, I'd argue that your question is backwards; calling `estimatedDocumentCount()` is always inherently *safe* in terms of *unlikely to bring your environment to its knees*, with the caveat that you're looking at metadata there, so in certain scenarios (sharded clusters, etc), it might be slightly inaccurate. However, realistically, in an environment where you've deployed Mongo, things are always going to be 'slightly inaccurate'; i.e., whatever count I grab at this instant is likely to be inaccurate an instant from now anyway.

In contrast, the no-filter form of `countDocuments()` is inherently unsafe, and the first time you call it on a gigantic collection will be a powerful learning experience regarding `O(1)` vs `O(N)`.

Comment: thanks; in my case, the counting is filtered and I'm using it to enforce a maximum number of documents created each day (from a business rule)... in this sense, an estimate doesn't feel appropriate, but I wanted to double check

Comment: maybe I should rephrase the question: in which scenarios the estimatedDocumentsCount() gives a precise result, identical to countDocuments() ?